# Zimbra upgrade from 8.0.6 to 8.8.6

Tags: upgrade, zimbra

I just inherited a old single-server Zimbra 8.0.6 installation running on 64-bit CentOS 6.5. Being both the OS and Zimbra so old, I plan to update at the next maintenance window. However I would like to first do a reality-check asking on the forum.

I read the guide [here](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_Releases/8.7.0/Upgrade) (I can't find anything 8.8 specific) and my current plan is to:

- stop all mail flow;
- update the OS via yum and reboot;
- stop again all mail flow;
- upgrade Zimbra to the latest release (8.8.6 at time of writing this post).

The entire upgrade cycle will be preceded by a snapshot of the virtual machine on which it runs, as well by a lab-testing on a dedicated machine.

Can I ask:

- is my plan sound, or flawed?
- is upgrading the OS first a good choice?
- there is something to take into account when performing the upgrade (ie: common pitfall which should be avoided)?

Thank you all.

Comment: I am sure that you found this, but if not (and if your upgrade isn't already long done), here is the [Zimbra Installation and Upgrade forum](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewforum.php?f=13)

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to install zimbra 8.0.6 in Centos7 And Sync the latest data to Centos7 from Centos6.5.Then better to perform upgrdation steps to Zimbra 8.8 in Centos7.

We have done the same and we Achieved.